# MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated

Tags: python

Here is the error below that keeps appearing after I run the python script:

> The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.

Comment: and what is the problem..? please share more code and details

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error.  It's just a warning message.